# How do I insert a new list variable into an existing DynamoDB Table Item using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb

I would like to add a new list of strings to all the items that I have in an existing DynamoDB table.  The following does what I want for one of the items:

```
var ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({ apiVersion: '2012-08-10' });
var params = {
  TableName: 'SampleTable',
  Key: {
    "Date": { S: "01.04.2020" },
    "TimeOfDay": { S: "morning" }
  },
  UpdateExpression: "SET ReferenceList = :rl",
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ":rl": 
    {
      L: [
        { S: "string1" },
        { S: "string2" },
        { S: "string3" }
      ]
    }
  }
};
ddb.updateItem(params, function (err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  else console.log(data);
});
```

However, I would like to pass in a variable to the ExpressionAttributeValues for the list since the number of strings is different for each item.  Something like:

```
ExpressionAttributeValues: { ":rl": refList }
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how to define refList.  I tried the following:

```
var refList = `{ L: [ { S: "string1" }, { S: "string2" }, { S: "string3" ]}`;
```

and also,

```
var refList = AWS.DynamoDB.Converter.Marshall({list: ['string1', 'string2', 'string3']});
```

but neither of these attempts worked.  How do I construct a list object that Dynamo handles and how do I pass it to the ExpressionAttributeValues?

Answer (score 1):

I found something that works, whether or not it is the best approach remains to be seen.

I changed the code to the following:

```
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
var refList = ["string1", "string2", "string3"];
var params = {
  TableName: 'SampleTable',
  Key: {
    "Date":  "01.04.2020" ,
    "TimeOfDay":  "morning" 
  },
  UpdateExpression: "SET ReferenceList = :rl",
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ":rl": refList
  }
};
docClient.update(params, function (err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  else console.log(data);
});
```

This seemed to work, and I could see the new list attached to this item in my DynamoDB table.  The following link was what I needed to help with this solution: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.Js.03.html#GettingStarted.Js.03.03